# Is it normal to have `<>` and `</>` as the enclosing elements for adjacent JSX elements in react? Can I use `<div>`and `</div>` instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently tried to run the following code

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ContactCard />
      <ContactCard />
      <ContactCard />
    </>
  );
};
```

However, I came across the following error.

```
Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?
```

I solved the problem by wrapping the elements in `<>` and `</>`, but is this normal? Surprisingly, I couldn't find the corresponding "empty" brackets in the rendered HTML. Wouldn't it make more sense to use `<div>`and `</div>` as the enclosing JSX elements instead?

Comment: Yes that concept is called Fragments in React and is absolutely fine to use . Check this for details https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: Presumably you mean you got that error *before* adding `<></>`. The error message told you it was a JSX fragment - did you research what that meant? Given that it was suggested by React, what makes you wonder if it's normal? Did you try using `<div>` instead - what happened? Sharing your research helps everyone, and likely leads to a better reception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered the requirement for React.Fragments

Sometimes its necessary to add a list of JSX elements (like you have) to the DOM in the return of your component. The issue is that all components must return a JSX element, as in a single JSX element. Thus, you cannot return a list of unwrapped elements from a component.

In order to return a list of JSX elements from a component, you need to wrap them in what is called a Fragment.

A Fragment is a JSX component which enables your component to return multiple elements without wrapping them with an element which appears in the DOM (such as a div). This is why you would not find them rendered in the HTML.

<></> is short for <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

[More here about React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the purpose of <> </> they are not inserted in the dom.

That can be handy for html tables for exemple where you can't insert a div between tr and td

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly normal. The difference is that the <></> will not render any element in your HTML, while `<div></div>` will render an additional div and may screw up your css or something.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** these are normal: as those are the shorthand for [React.Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).
Those fragments act as wrapping JSX element - as div would - however those ones do not render any useless div unless it is really needed
Check the link provided for more details